# Cardinality of an index in a MySQL table is equal to table's row size

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have just included an index to a MyISAM table and the cardinality appears to be 1 million something which is exactly the number of rows in the table. In fact it needed to be 315 because distinct count returns 315. And then I have realized that there are 3 other such indexes (equal to tables's row size), and all their distinct counts are way below. So, what could be the reason these indexes' carnalities are equal to table's row size?

Note: There are 97 columns and 27 indexes.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `isemri` (
  `RECNO` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MUSTERI_RECNO` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MUSTERI_PER_RECNO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YIL` smallint(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `ISEMRI_NO` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `BOLGE` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `URUN_BARKOD` varchar(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''''',
  `ISTEK_TIPI` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `MUSTERI_NO` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVIS_CAGRI_TAR` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MUSTERI_PER` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVIS_BAS_TAR` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVIS_BIT_TAR` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ISTEGI_ALAN` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_CIHAZ` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_CIHAZ_ADI` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_MARKA` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_MARKA_ADI` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_MODEL` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_MODEL_ADI` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_SERI_NO` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVIS_VEREN` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVIS_TURU` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ARIZA_ACIKLAMASI` mediumtext,
  `ARIZASERVIS_ACIKLAMA` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACILIYET_DERECESI` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `SERVIS_DURUMU` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `GERI_BILDIRIM` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `KON_GEL_DON_TAR` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `GERI_BILDIRIM_TARIHI` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAHMINI_TESLIM_TARIHI` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `YAPILANLAR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YAPILANLAR_M` mediumtext,
  `SERVIS_YERI` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOPLAM` float(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `KDV_TOP` float(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GENEL_TOPLAM` float(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSERT_USER` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GIRIS_KARGO_NO` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSERT_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UPDATE_USER` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPDATE_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `BARKOD` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SERVIS_BITIS` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `GARANTI_BELGENO` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GARANTI_TARIHI` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EL_ISEMRI_NO` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ONAY_TARIHI` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ONAYLAYAN` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ALAN1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ALAN2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ALAN3` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ALAN4` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOLAR_KURU` float DEFAULT '2',
  `EURO_KURU` float DEFAULT '2',
  `KDV` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `BILGILENDIR` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `TESLIM_SEKLI` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TESLIM_NOTU` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ARIZA_TIP_NO` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ARIZASERVIS_TIP` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GETIREN_KARGO_FRM` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERV_ALAN1` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERV_ALAN2` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOSYA__` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HAKEDIS_DURUM` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `HAKEDIS_FATURANO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HAKEDIS_FATURA_DURUM` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ONAY_DURUM` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `MONTAJ_KODU` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `urun_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gondKargoFirmasi` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gondKargoNo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gondIrsNo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gondGelTar` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `BAYI_KODU` varchar(50) DEFAULT '0',
  `HAKEDIS_TARIHI` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `HAKEDIS_ONAY_PERSONEL` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HURDA_CTRL` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `DOSYA` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `RANDEVU_TARIHI` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MUSTERI_ACIKLAMA` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLASIYER` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FIRMA_SERINO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTAJ_KART_NO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERINO2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SATICI_FIRMA` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_DEGISIM_DURUMU` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URUN_HASAR_DURUMU` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BOLGE_2` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `KILIT` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ON_ONAY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RANDEVU_BITIS_TARIHI` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'iş emri randavü bitiş tarihi',
  `URUN_KALITE` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BOLGE_X` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REWORK` enum('0','1') DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Rework olup olmadığını gösteriyor.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`RECNO`),
  KEY `MUSTERI_NO` (`MUSTERI_NO`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `EL_ISEMRI_NO` (`EL_ISEMRI_NO`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `MUSTERI_RECNO` (`MUSTERI_RECNO`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ISEMRI_NO` (`ISEMRI_NO`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ALAN1` (`ALAN1`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `URUN_SERI_NO` (`URUN_SERI_NO`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `SERVIS_TURU` (`SERVIS_TURU`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `SERVIS_DURUMU` (`SERVIS_DURUMU`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ISTEK_TIPI` (`ISTEK_TIPI`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `urun_id` (`urun_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `URUN_CIHAZ` (`URUN_CIHAZ`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `HAKEDIS_DURUM` (`HAKEDIS_DURUM`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `HAKEDIS_TARIHI` (`HAKEDIS_TARIHI`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `HAKEDIS_ONAY_PERSONEL` (`HAKEDIS_ONAY_PERSONEL`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `SERVIS_BAS_TAR` (`SERVIS_BAS_TAR`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `BOLGE_2` (`BOLGE_2`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `URUN_MARKA` (`URUN_MARKA`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `URUN_MODEL` (`URUN_MODEL`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `MUSTERI_PER` (`MUSTERI_PER`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `MONTAJ_KODU` (`MONTAJ_KODU`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `BOLGE` (`BOLGE`),
  KEY `HAKEDIS_FATURANO` (`HAKEDIS_FATURANO`),
  KEY `REWORK` (`REWORK`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `SERVIS_BITIS` (`SERVIS_BITIS`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `HAKEDIS_FATURA_DURUM` (`HAKEDIS_FATURA_DURUM`),
  KEY `MUSTERI_PER_RECNO` (`MUSTERI_PER_RECNO`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1335476 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

SHOW TABLE STATUS:

```
Name: isemri
Engine: MyISAM
Version: 10
Rpw_format: Dynamic
Rows: 1328150
Avg_row_length: 459
Data_length: 610624628
Max_data_length: 281474976710655
Index_length: 420404224
Data_free: 0
Auto_icrement: 1335384
Create_time: 2016-02-12 16:22:12
Update_time: 2016-02-13 10:43:59
Check_time: 2016-02-12 17:52:23
Collation: utf8_general_ci
Checksum: 
Create_options: pack_keys=0 row_format=DYNAMIC
Comment:
```

Distinct count:

```
URUN_SERI_NO: 1012754
SERVIS_BAS_TAR: 1300066
BOLGE_2: 5
MUSTERI_PER_RECNO: 319
```

[image: indexes]

Comment: Maybe the index's columns are not the ones who make row distinct ? If you select count(*) from (select * from table group by <index's columns>) t1, what do you get ?

Comment: @JesusTheHun, I get 316.

Comment: just to be sure your cardinality is up to date : analyze table <table>

Comment: @JesusTheHun, it says status OK. But carnality is still 1324572.

Comment: Is your table partitioned?

Comment: @Shadow, it is not partitioned.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`; something subtle may be going on.

Comment: @RickJames, I've provided them above. Also here is the [SHOW INDEX FROM isemri](http://i.imgur.com/CFWd38Y.png).